# Is it safe to convert tables from MyISAM to InnoDB?

Tags: database, mysql, innodb

I have inherited a WP site (with WP5.1 and WooCommerce 2.6.14, LearnDash 2.5.4 and few other smaller plugins).

From screenshot you can see that it is a mix and match of MyISAM and InnoDB tables.

We are experiencing table locking related problems (which essentially slow site down and result in 503 errors).

Even on such a simple table as `wp_options` we seem to have up to 10seconds lock times. Also on `wp_posts`.

Is it safe to convert tables from MyISAM to InnoDB? (we think that avoiding MyISAM table-level locking and switching to InnoDB row-level locking may help solve our issues).

ps. MySQL version 5.6.36-82.1-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 82.1, Revision 1a00d79 (SiteGround)

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you take a backup, convert them over, then test the site to see if it still works? I don't see why it wouldn't be safe, what are you worried might happen?

Comment: Well, the whole setup is flimsy and I do not have confidence about backup/restore mechanisms the hosting provider offers.  So I have to tread lightly. attempt to create staging environment failed; support agent tried 'repairing tables' and brought down all site; restored from yesterdays backup; i tried making simple db-dump and source into new db - this process took 15 mins and only worked as of 2nd attempt... Also as there's myriad plugins and they do who knows what - there's no reliable way to 'test site if it still works' - as pages may work, but some cron plugin hook may be breaking...

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: @DimitryK Ready to make some progress?  Consider posting additional information requested on Jun 2, 2019, please.